Creating a docx file with a specific text in flutter/dart
I have a string which i want to add to an empty word document. I want to create a new word docx and add that string to it and be able to share it as well.
Code:
static Future<void> createDocx(String docText) async {
    print(docText);

    final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/docFile/docfile.docx');
    final bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

    var docx = await DocxTemplate.fromBytes(bytes);
    print(docx);
    Content c = Content();
    c
      ..add(TextContent("content", "hi my name is yashi"))
      ..add(TextContent('name', 'yashi'));

    print('Content object: $c');

    // Generate the document with replaced variables
    try {
      print('hiii');
      final docGenerated =
          await docx.generate(c, tagPolicy: TagPolicy.saveText);
      print('hi2');
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final filePath = '${directory.path}/output.docx';
      print(filePath);
      final file = File(filePath);
      if (docGenerated != null) await file.writeAsBytes(docGenerated);
      await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(filePath)]);
      print('Document created: $filePath');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error generating document: $e');
    }
}

Console output:
I/flutter (14867): Instance of ‘DocxTemplate’
I/flutter (14867): Content object: {content: {}, name: {}}
I/flutter (14867): hiii
I/flutter (14867): Error generating document: Unsupported operation: Cannot modify an unmodifiable list

(It also prints docText correctly)
This is how my word template looks like:

I don't understand why is the value of content and name empty in content object. what’s wrong?
Some other ways to achieve the desired use case are also welcome.

You are trying to modify an unmodifyable list. This happens when the docx template or the data passed into the Content class doesn't match the expected structure.
Couple of advices:
${content}
${name}

^ Ensure your docfile.docx contains placeholders like this.
Use TagPolicy.removeUnmatched to remove unused placeholders instead. This will help filter out the ones that don't match.
See if something like this works (you might have to modify it out a little, and I have commented out most of what it does in details to help out jic)
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:docx_template/docx_template.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:share_plus/share_plus.dart';

Future<void> createDocx(String docText) async {
  try {
    // Load the Word template from assets
    final data = await rootBundle.load('assets/docFile/docfile.docx');
    final bytes = data.buffer.asUint8List();

    // Initialize the DocxTemplate
    var docx = await DocxTemplate.fromBytes(bytes);

    // Define content for the placeholders
    Content c = Content()
      ..add(TextContent("content", docText)) // Maps to `${content}` in template
      ..add(TextContent("name", "yashi"));  // Maps to `${name}` in template

    // Generate the document with the replaced variables
    final docGenerated = await docx.generate(c, tagPolicy: TagPolicy.removeUnmatched);

    // Save the generated document to the application's document directory
    if (docGenerated != null) {
      final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final filePath = '${directory.path}/output.docx';
      final file = File(filePath);
      await file.writeAsBytes(docGenerated);

      // Share the generated document
      await Share.shareXFiles([XFile(filePath)]);
      print('Document created and shared: $filePath');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error generating document: $e');
  }
}


Hi, it is still not working.
I have added the word template also in the question, it is correct or not.
it contains 2 placeholders - content and name
Also tagPolicy: TagPolicy.removeUnmatched gives an error
we can only use removeAll, saveText or saveNullified
